# Cannot successfully use Jquery .delegate() method

Tags: jquery, html, delegates

In a desperate attempt to make the .delegate method of Jquery work as I need it to. I would like the delegate function to acknowledge the change or click on the radio buttons returned from a loop.

However, using the delegate method is not working with my code.

```
$("#MailGroupResults").delegate("input[type=radio]", "click", function () {
        alert('works');
});
<div class="secResultCon" id="MailGroupResultsCon">
  <div class="secResult" id="MailGroupResults">
  <!-- Following Code is generated by jquery loop -->
  <p>Mailbox Permissions</p>
  <div class="optionResources">
   <div class="optionResourceMini">
    Group
   </div>

  <div class="optionResourceMini">

  <div class="switch">
   <input type="radio" id="11" class="checkbox" name="Jindabyne Tickets">
   <input type="radio" id="10" class="checkbox" name="Jindabyne Tickets" checked="">
   <label class="cb-enable"><span>On</span></label>
   <label class="cb-disable selected"><span>Off</span></label>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**- What doesn't work**

I used a javascript function that pulls information from a database using ajax. It will display a list of mailboxes each assigned with a radio button either enabled or disabled depending on the result.

When I click on the radio buttons, the function below, does not do anything, meaning to alert box. However, if I copy the html that is generated into my code it will work...confused.

```
$("#MailGroupResults").delegate("input[type=radio]", "click", function () {
        alert('works');
});
```

**How Javascript is generating child elements**

```
function GetUserMailGroups(userName) {
        $("#Mailloading").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ADMethods.asmx/GetEmailGroups',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{ userName : "' + userName + '"}',
            success: function (response) {
                $("#Mailloading").fadeOut();
                GetMailGroups = false;
                var memberOfMail = response.d;
                i = 0;
                // Create Javascript Array to contain the Mailbox information so that we can run check against when 
                // a switch is pressed. Therefore, on form submission we can identify changes of permissions
                arrSize = memberOfMail.length;
                arrMail = new Array(arrSize);
                $.each(memberOfMail, function (index, MailInfo) {
                    arrMail[i] = new Array(2);
                    var html = '<div class="optionResources">';
                    var html = html + '<div class="optionResourceMini">' + MailInfo.GroupName + '</div>';
                    var html = html + '<div class="optionResourceMini">';
                    var html = html + '<div class="switch">';
                    // Apply returned data to array
                    arrMail[i][0] = MailInfo.GroupName
                    if (MailInfo.MemberOf) {
                        var html = html + '<input type="radio" id="' + i + '1" class="checkbox" name="' + MailInfo.GroupName + '" checked />';
                        var html = html + '<input type="radio" id="' + i + '0" class="checkbox" name="' + MailInfo.GroupName + '" />';
                        var html = html + '<label class="cb-enable selected"><span>On</span></label>';
                        var html = html + '<label class="cb-disable "><span>Off</span></label>';
                        arrMail[i][1] = true;
                    } else {
                        var html = html + '<input type="radio" id="' + i + '1" class="checkbox" name="' + MailInfo.GroupName + '" />';
                        var html = html + '<input type="radio" id="' + i + '0" class="checkbox" name="' + MailInfo.GroupName + '" checked />';
                        var html = html + '<label class="cb-enable"><span>On</span></label>';
                        var html = html + '<label class="cb-disable selected"><span>Off</span></label>';
                        arrMail[i][1] = false;
                    }

                    var html = html + '</div>';
                    var html = html + '</div>';
                    var html = html + '</div> ';
                    $("#MailGroupResults").append(html);
                    // Increase i integer for array index.
                    i++;
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

I managed to get the same method to work in jsfiddle. narrowing it down very basic method, which the loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/aFSmF/4/[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aFSmF/4/)

Comment: *"I managed to get the same method to work in jsfiddle"*: Then I understand what your problem is/what you would like to know. The code you posted here is not very useful, since it mixes JS and HTML and it's unclear when you execute what. Also, what exactly *"does not work"*?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work, the code in your fiddle works.

Comment: You should be using on() with jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: @claw Is `#MailGroupResults` a static element?

Comment: @undefined yes it is static. #optionResources and all its children are dynamically generated.

Comment: Show the actual code for how MailGroupResults is populated.

Comment: And when are you calling the delegate line? ready? load? inline?

Comment: Sorry, the delegate is at load under $(function() { // all jquery }

Comment: Why do you have i when there is index? You also should not keep declaring var html over and over again. Once is enough. Also what browser[s]?

Answer (score 0):

Put the delegate in document.ready. you are calling delegate on empty array as the DOM is not initialized yet and does not contain element with that ID. Moving that delegate function into document.ready will have events properly registered. That was the basic reason your jsfiddle is working and actual code is not working

Comment: comment above says it is in $() so it is already set to ready.

Comment: @epascarello saw OP comment now

Answer (score 0):

[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) has been replaced with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery 1.8.

```
$("#MailGroupResults").delegate("input[type=radio]", "click", function () {
    alert('works');
});
```

should look like this with the use of on.

```
$("#MailGroupResults").on("click", 'input[type="radio"]', function () {
    alert('works');
});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", '#MailGroupResults input[type="radio"]', function () {
    alert('works');
});
```

Also give your radio buttons a name attribute and ids in HTML4 can not start with a number.

Comment: unfortunately still no luck,I updated to 1.8 however, the generated html is still not being detected with the on() method.